# bash function returns always true

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script

```
function fun1(){
    return 0;
}

function fun2(){
    return 1;
}

if  fun1  && fun2  ;then 
echo "success"
else 
echo "failure"
fi
```

which works fine..
I need to wrap this up in double brackets. I am trying to do like this.

```
if  [[ fun1 ]]  && [[ fun2 ]] ;then 
echo "success"
else 
echo "failure"
fi
```

However it always returns success regardless of the return values of the functions..

Can anybody tell me where am I going wrong?
However If if run witho

Comment: Why? Do you understand what `[[ ... ]]` actually does?

Comment: "I need to wrap this up in double brackets." No, you don't. If you do, please make the reasons clear in your post, because as written, that's not true, and you demonstrate is with a valid call of 'if fun1 && fun2 ;then`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if  fun1
```

means that, use the result of function `fun1` as if condition. So it worked as expected.

```
if  [[ fun1 ]]
```

Once you used `[[ or [`, you are calling a command `test` (or a new powerful command `test` for `[[`), so the `fun1` would be argument for the `test` command. Your checking thus becomes: "if `fun1` is not an empty string". Thus, it returns always true.